# How to reduce inductor heating in buck converter?

Tags: power-supply, inductor, buck

I am designing a simple buck converter to drive 9 V, 3 A LED. Supply can vary between 20 and 30 V. I used the TI Power Designer Tool to calculate the inductance value and other parameters. Here is the schematic:

[image]

[image]

After driving the load, everything is fine except that the inductor is getting heated to almost 85°C.

My PCB has to go into an enclosed box so this is not OK.

Strange thing is, the MOSFET is not getting hot at all, so the gate driving is fine, I guess. I have no clue why only the inductor gets heated in a buck converter.

Please suggest what factors concerning the inductor I should look into.

Vin : 20-30V
switching frequency : 350kHz

Inductor HCM1A1307V2-330-R : [Datasheet](https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/electronic-components/resources/data-sheet/eaton-hcm1a1307v2-automotive-power-inductor-data-sheet.pdf)

Mosfet SI_4288DY : [Datsheet](http://farnell.com/datasheets/1441695.pdf)

Diode SS54 : [Datasheet](http://farnell.com/datasheets/1441695.pdf)

Driver IR2110 : [Datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR2110-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c80333167e)
Here is the calculation screenshot of TI tool:
[image]

Comment: Data sheet links for the inductor and silicon devices are required.

Comment: What are  the values of: Vin, switching frequency, inductor maximum current, inductor peak to peak ripple current?

Comment: What switching frequency are you using? Please put this detail and the links into your question and not in comments. This isn't a forum.

Comment: @VishweshGM Please edit the part numbers and links into your question. Readers are not expected to dig through the comments for such important information.

Comment: Why does your driver chip 0 volts connect to the MOSFET source (thus shorting the output to ground). Please show a more consistent circuit where all the components used are in 1 schematic with no ambiguity and, all the power rails are clearly indicated. Why haven't you added the DS for the MOSFET driver in your question.

Comment: @Andyaka : As per my knowledge, IR2110 driving side ground is for bootstrap circuit. I added datsheet now.

Comment: Have you worked out the inductor's power dissipation, taking notes 3,5 on page 2 into account?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*From page 14 of the [datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/87/eaton-hcm1a1307v2-automotive-power-inductor-data-s-1627668.pdf).*

Your temperature rise is much higher than expected so I'd check that you're not saturating the inductor. A 65°C temperature rise above ambient suggests that you're running at 7.5 A.

The DC resistance is listed as 40.8 mΩ. 7.5 A will cause a dissipation of \$ P = I^2R = 7.5^2 \times 0.04 = 2.25\ \text W \$.